# Include pre-compiled content in MVC View

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have some pre-compiled html content which I want to include in my View like:

```
@*View Start*@ 

Some precompiled html

Some view content

Some precompiled html

Some view content

Some precompiled html

@*View End*@
```

I have already thought of some ways but each of them has some GREAT downsides that I don't want to use it. these are the ways I have thought of:

- Although these html codes are pre-compiled with fixed content they may change time to time (let say weekly) so can not be included in view itself
- They're rather big in size so I don't think having them in database would be wise (would increase database size and data-bandwith)
- Having them in html files and writing them into view using C# functions something like `@File.ReadAllText("page-customized-head.html")` and this would be slow and would make hard disk busier than it should.

I want to know if anybody can suggest a better solution or a way to improve the above solutions.

**Edit:**
I had put aside solutions like ajax, as in this situation was not suitable for my design.  After @Hadee's comment I noticed that my description is not complete, so I'm adding some more description.

These content files can be unique for different pages of different users as user can customize css, js. add - edit remove html elements. So each user may have several pages that each page may have several different "Pre-Compiled" section.

As these content may be the head section of the page, may contain css, js (that following content may rely on it), ... **ajax** is not suitable in here.

And as for partial views, I don't see any different between them and having the content written into html file. Actually I think html file and `@File.ReadAllText("page-customized-head.html")` would be faster, as unlike `.cshtml` it does not need compiling.

Comment: Why you don't try partial view? Or html result of ajax call?

Comment: @Hadee my question was not complete I think. I edited my question. thanks for your comment

Comment: One option for you could be `MVC Areas`.